# how to use IN operator in laravel query (eleqouent and raw query)?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing, laravel-5

I need to use the `IN` operator to get the data from the database. I tried using it as below and got an error:

```
$pr =DB::('select * from prstuff p where p.pid in (select pid from prdrop)');
```

I am new to Laravel and don't know exactly how to use the operators like `IN`, so please explain to me how to use it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can set the custom select in `DB::raw()` like this :

```
DB::select(DB::raw('select * from prstuff p where p.pid in (select pid from prdrop)'));
```

or you can use `whereIn()` like this:

```
DB::table('prstuff')
->select('*')
->whereIn('pid', function($query)
{
    $query->select('pid')
    ->from('prdrop');
})
->get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You are not calling any funtion on your db class. You can call the select function like this `DB::select ()`

```
$pr =DB::select('select * from prstuff p where p.pid in (select pid from prdrop)');
```

Comment: actually i forgot to write 'select' here .. 
i used in the same way, but didn't work.
i have got the below asnwer working

Comment: Sure u could also use DB::raw to wrap your query