# Raw queries no output

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi can ask some help on this raw query it has no output,

```
   $userproj_id = UserProject::select('projid')->where('user_id', $id)->get()->toArray();
        $flattenid = array_flatten($userproj_id);
        foreach ($flattenid as $projid) {
            $projidarr [] = $projid;
        }


  $users = DB::select('select * from project where projid in  ( ? )  and user_id = 3 ', $projidarr );
```

but if I will manually do like this, it works fine..

```
$users = DB::select('select * from project where projid in  ( ? )  and user_id = 3 ', ['12345']);
```

but when I do this manually no output again.

```
 $users = DB::select('select * from project where projid in  ( ? )  and user_id = 3 ', ['12345','11111']);
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35725251/4248472 ?

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your bindings array, you have to many parameters - the SQL needs only one, and you are providing two.
A proper parameter list would be [implode(',', [12345, 1111])] but in this case it would be a string and the result wouldn't be correct as well

What about this?

```
DB::table('project')
->whereIn('projid', [12345, 1111])
->where('user_id', '=', 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Raw Query:

```
$users = DB::select('select * from project where projid in  ('. implode(',', $projidarr).')  and user_id = 3 ');
```

and Laravel query:

```
DB::table('project')
->whereIn('projid', $projidarr)
->where('user_id', '=', 3);
```